# NSTimezone get abbreviation from timezoneId

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, timezone

In my IOS App I have a timezoneid like "America/Los_Angeles" and I would like to get its abbreviation "PST".

I have written the following code:

```
NSTimeZone* theTimezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:_timezone];
    _timezoneAbbreviation = theTimezone.abbreviation;
```

My issue is `_timezoneAbbreviation` returns always a string like "UTC-x" or "UTC+x" instead of the appropriate abbreviation.

If I'm looking in the `NSDictionary` returned by `[NSTimeZone abbreviations]` it contains the right abbreviation (for example PST for "America/Los_Angeles").

Any idea?

Sebastien.

Comment: Be careful with time zone abbreviations.  In the summer, you would want PDT instead of PST for the same `America/Los_Angeles` zone.  And for abbreviations like `CST`, there are [many ambiguities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: It's supposed to be managed by NSTimeZone -> Extract from Apple Doc "Note that the abbreviation may be different at different dates. For example, during daylight savings time the US/Eastern time zone has an abbreviation of “EDT.” At other times, its abbreviation is “EST.”"

Comment: Sure, but somehow you need to indicate the date to use as a basis for making that determination.  You could ask for a time zone abbreviation at some specific time (like right now, or last month, etc.), but I don't see how it could guess correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of the `abbreviation` method seems to be locale dependent. If I set the region format to "United States", then your code actually returns "PST". If i set the region format to "Germany/German", it returns "GMT-8" (tested on the iOS Simulator).

But

```
[theTimezone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard
                    locale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]
```

gives "PST", independent of the region format.

(I am aware that this is only a partial solution. It returns the desired result only
for American time zones. But perhaps it points into the right direction to solve 
the problem.)

Comment: Good answer! I will investigate more on that direction.

Comment: One custom solution is to use its Default Abbreviation Dictionary and find out particular Abbreviation from it.
[NSTimezone abbreviationDictionary];

Answer (score 0):

Directly use the dictionary. Or create your own dictionary so you have full control over it.

Comment: I could do that but from Apple Documentation the method - (NSString *)abbreviation is supposed to return "PST"...